# What is the advantage of using heredoc in PHP?

Tags: php, heredoc

What is the advantage of using [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) in PHP, and can you show an example?

Comment: There is no strong reason alternates are better than heredocs

Comment: I've edited this to be more constructive, and made the question community wiki as it is quite subjective. Note, The community may still close this, I elected to leave it open because you are getting quality answers.

Comment: Why exactly is this question not considered constructive?

Comment: heredocs is a godsend when I write PHP code that generates HTML and javascript, and I need to utilize variables to embed literal values within that generated code. regarding 'control structures', i perform that external to the heredoc block and embed the data accordingly

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The heredoc syntax is much cleaner to me and it is really useful for multi-line strings and avoiding quoting issues.  Back in the day I used to use them to construct SQL queries:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
select *
  from $tablename
 where id in [$order_ids_list]
   and product_name = "widgets"
SQL;
```

To me this has a lower probability of introducing a syntax error than using quotes:

```
$sql = "
select *
  from $tablename
 where id in [$order_ids_list]
   and product_name = \"widgets\"
";
```

Another point is to avoid escaping double quotes in your string:

```
$x = "The point of the \"argument" was to illustrate the use of here documents";
```

The problem with the above is the syntax error (the missing escaped quote) I just introduced as opposed to here document syntax:

```
$x = <<<EOF
The point of the "argument" was to illustrate the use of here documents
EOF;
```

It is a bit of style, but I use the following as rules for single, double and here documents for defining strings:

- **Single** quotes are used when the string is a constant like `'no variables here'`
- **Double** quotes when I can put the string on a single line and require variable interpolation or an embedded single quote `"Today is ${user}'s birthday"`
- **Here** documents for multi-line strings that require formatting and variable interpolation.

Comment: Nitpick on your SQL example: You should not use double quotes within there in the first place. That only works with MySQL, and only when that server doesn't run in `--ansi` compliant mode. SQL strings *must* use single quotes.

Comment: @mario It was for illustration of the problem with using double quotes in general not about the specifics of the sql

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel useless is a strong word as it does build the string.  Have you never had a situation where you want to construct a long string with double quotes in it and missed escaping them properly?  Here documents have their place and it is good on php to support them.

Comment: Not to say that placing variables into a query directly is a bad, bad manners :-P

Comment: well, why is this better then:
    $var = " my string".\r\n
           " is multiline".\r\n
           " because i like it";  ?

(ps: lines won't break in the comments , so just imagine they are breaking :P)

Comment: Also in this case, HEREDOC allows you to start writing in a new line, keeping it much more sight-firendly without introducing a line break in the beggining of the string.

Comment: @Wes and @mario
This is ANSI SQL : ``SELECT * FROM "order" WHERE "table"='1'``

Comment: StackOverflow needs to change syntax highlighting to handle `HEREDOC`s

Comment: "Not to say that placing variables into a query directly is a bad, bad manners". This is not true at all. Placing non-validated input into SQL statements is "bad manners". Placing variables inside SQL statements is sometimes necessary.

Comment: What does mean by "Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties. Since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables."? Someone, please update the answer explaining meaning of these sentences.

Comment: @PHPFan You can't initialize a class property with a variable as a default value: `private string $welcome = "Hello, $name";` is invalid. Prior to PHP 5.3, you could not use heredoc to initialize class properties at all, but in PHP 5.3 and later you can initialize class properties using heredoc as long as it does not contain any variables (because initializing class properties using variables is not valid).

Answer (score 74):

Heredoc's are a great alternative to quoted strings because of increased readability and maintainability. You don't have to escape quotes and (good) IDEs or text editors will use the proper syntax highlighting.

A *very* common example: echoing out HTML from within PHP:

```
$html = <<<HTML
  <div class='something'>
    <ul class='mylist'>
      <li>$something</li>
      <li>$whatever</li>
      <li>$testing123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
HTML;

// Sometime later
echo $html;
```

It is easy to read and easy to maintain.

The alternative is echoing quoted strings, which end up containing escaped quotes and IDEs aren't going to highlight the syntax for that language, which leads to poor readability and more difficulty in maintenance.

**Updated answer for *[Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)***

Of course you wouldn't want to see an SQL query highlighted as HTML. To use other languages, simply change the language in the syntax:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
       SELECT * FROM table
SQL;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know PHP's "[escape from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)" feature?

Comment: Escaping from PHP is fine sometimes, but when you are echoing a lot of stuff, your syntax highlighting breaks, you have to type more characters by simple escaping from PHP and PHP has more commands to execute instead of a single echo. Also, you can set a Heredoc string to a variable and echo it later. Escaping PHP for your HTML means it gets printed out then and there. Can't save it for later.

Comment: 1. you can use output buffering to save the output. 2. You were using echo in your first example. 3. (good) IDE's or text editors **NEVER** break HTML highlighting when you are using escaping from PHP. 4. What IDE does syntax highlight for HEREDOC and what language rules used? Is it okay to see an SQL query highlighted as HTML text?

Comment: The text editor I use, Sublime Text, does the proper Syntax highlighting just fine for Heredoc's. Regarding the language, I updated my answer to illustrate how to change the language for the Heredoc. It sounds like you have some reading to do regarding this topic. Not sure why you would downvote something without even understanding the basics of the topic...

Comment: 5. You can't use PHP controls structures inside of heredoc, which makes it tool of extremely limited use.

Comment: A Heredoc is a PHP string. Of course you can't use control structures in a string. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: That's the point, if you didn't get it. There are 2 major scenarios of outputting HTML: 1. Sending out large block of raw HTML/JS with no PHP variables at all. You don't need heredoc for this as you can store your HTML in a file and read it as is. 2. An HTML template, with all the business logic data output. You can't use heredoc here because of the reason mentioned above. The only use left for the heredoc is storing some odd HTML fragments like HTML emails.

Comment: Though I liked that language hinting feature. Just tested it with NetBeans.  At least out of the box, it highlights no syntax in heredocs, despite of the hints in the label.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Heredoc's to only apply to strings of HTML. Heredoc's are simply an alternate way of defining a string, whether it be HTML or an SQL query or anything you want. They are easier to write and maintain, Wes's answer above shows that quite obviously (which if you note has the correct syntax highlighting. Don't complain to me about NetBeans failing). I'm not sure why you seem so bent on down-voting an answer on a community wiki question... Believe it or not, the original PHP developers may have included Heredoc's in PHP because it might actually be useful in some cases...

Answer (score 9):

Some IDEs highlight the code in heredoc strings automatically - which makes using heredoc for XML or HTML visually appealing.

I personally like it for longer parts of i.e. XML since I don't have to care about quoting quote characters and can simply paste the XML.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, all the reasons are subjective.
It's more like a matter of taste rather than a reason.

Personally, I find heredoc quite useless and use it occasionally, most of the time when I need to get some HTML into a variable and don't want to bother with output buffering, to form an HTML email message for example.

Formatting doesn't fit general indentation rules, but I don't think it's a big deal.

```
       //some code at it's proper level
       $this->body = <<<HERE
heredoc text sticks to the left border
but it seems OK to me.
HERE;
       $this->title = "Feedback";
       //and so on
```

As for the examples in the accepted answer, it is merely cheating.
String examples, in fact, being more concise if one won't cheat on them

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename
        WHERE id in [$order_ids_list]
        AND product_name = 'widgets'";

$x = 'The point of the "argument" was to illustrate the use of here documents';
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I would say heredoc is laziness. One can say that doing anything is laziness, as there are always more cumbersome ways to do anything.

For example, in certain situations you may want to output text, with embedded variables without having to fetch from a file and run a template replace. Heredoc allows you to forgo having to escape quotes, so the text you see is the text you output. Clearly there are some negatives, for example, you can't indent your heredoc, and that can get frustrating in certain situation, especially if your a stickler for unified syntax, which I am.