# Using <<<END in php

Tags: php

I have seen this through out several php file, and wanted to know, what purpose this served, if any and is it something i should use, or stay away from.

```
$html = <<<END
Some html stuff to output {$phpvariable
END;
```

vs.

```
$html = "Some html stuff to output {$phpvariable}";
```

Comment: Have you tried googling this?  Or checking the php.net manual?

Comment: It's called a [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: I didn't seem to find anything, yes i Googled. But now i know what its called, i found out some more info.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=three+less+than+signs+php&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS461US461&oq=three+less+than+signs+php&aqs=chrome..69i57.549j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 What was your query string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php

Comment: `php <<<END` - I know, it's a very complicated search query, no wonder you haven't found anything.

Comment: See what happens when you put a space before `END;` ;-) (grin)

Comment: This will save you time in the future http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often used when you need a string with multiple lines.

For example you can use:

```
$html = <<<END
this is
a multiline
string
END;
```

Instead of:

```
$html = "this is\na multiline\nstring";
```

In addition, "END" in this case is the end of the string. You can use other word for it. (e.g. EOS -for End Of String).

Have a look to the php documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: multiple lines is not the primary advantage of heredoc syntax

Comment: @Dagon So what's the primary advantage? Apart of multiline strings and avoid escaping double quotes I don't find any reason to use it.