# Override wp-login.php styles

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress CMS website where most labels are needed to be white. So the theme includes the below styles per form labels.

```
.login label {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

This above style is populated from within /wp-login.php file -- the style itself is located in the login.min.css (which is included directly within wp-login.php)

I need to override this ONLY for the forget password screen.

Luckily there are custom ID selectors for the two labels I need to be black in this instance. `#pass1 #pass2`

My problem is, I have NO ACCESS to `/wp-login.php` and `login.min.css` -- I have tried adding `!important` and declaring these two selectors within `header.php` but they were not read.

I need to somehow add; with current permission situation.

`#pass1 { color: #000 !important; }`

```
#pass2 { color: #000 !important; }
```

Could I use jQuery from `header.php` or `footer.php` to append the style? Would it be read?

Comment: Like others have said, you weren't supposed to modify any files in /wp-admin/ or /wp-includes/. They all get overwritten when Wordpress is updated. You want to keep all your changes in /wp-content/. Most likely in your theme's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best practice to edit any wp core files, so I'd advice not to touch wp-login.php anyway, since updating WordPress can reset things.

Instead, add this to your functions.php:

```
 // Custom login
function custom_login() {
        $files = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/css/login.css" />';
        echo $files;
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the login and forgot password screens are not theme dependent, your `header.php` file will not be read, so any styles you put in there won't affect these pages.

Add this to your `template.php` file

```
function my_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-login.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_stylesheet' );
```

and then add your custom styles to `style-login.css`

Answer (score 0):

`login_head` and `login_enqueue_scripts` are [called one after another](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-login.php#L105), so it doesn't matter which one you're using...

Using `wp_enqueue_style` is the best practice but it can be `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" ...>';` without problem.

I'm adding a solution because this isn't the kind of code that you just drop onto your theme `functions.php`. We want to keep the code running even if we swap themes. So a [*functionality plugin*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web) comes handy:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Login CSS
*/
function custom_login() {
   $CSS = <<<CSS
        <style>
            .login label {}
        </style>
CSS;
    echo $CSS;
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
```

Check the following to learn about the Heredoc sintax used to build the `$CSS` string: [What is the advantage of using Heredoc in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5673269/1287812)