# YouTube iframe API and WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube-api

I'm trying the following code on WordPress post page:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
    function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }
    function loadVideoById(val) {
        player.loadVideoById(val, 0, "large");
    }
</script>
```

However, nothing was displayed.

Comment: Are you adding this in the post editor or in the code somewhere? If in the post editor you can just paste the URL of your YouTube video and it will automatically embed it for you

Comment: I'm adding it in post editor, but the goal is not only to display YouTube video. I want to create some kind of video application and want to use YouTube IFrame API. The code I've posted above works in ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of code injection is better done with a [Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Instead of `document.createElement`, just use `wp_enqueue_script` to load the Iframe API and the rest of the script is printed by the shortcode. [PHP heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php) makes easy to build large configurable HTML strings.

Shortcode usage inside the post/page would be: **`[ytplayer id="M7lc1UVf-VE"]`**

```
add_shortcode( 'ytplayer', 'print_yt_player' );

function print_yt_player( $atts ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yt-iframe', 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' );
    $yt_id = $atts['id'];
    $html = <<<HTML
        <div id="player"></div>   
        <script>
            var player, done = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: '$yt_id',
                    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }    
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            function playVideo() {
                player.playVideo();
            }
            function pauseVideo() {
                player.pauseVideo();
            }
            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
            function loadVideoById(val) {
                player.loadVideoById(val, 0, "large");
            }
        </script>
HTML;
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `<p>` tags are being inserted when the page/post is saved. Two options:

1. [Disable wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter)
2. Include the script compressed (on a single line), like this:

   ```
   <div id="player"></div>
   <script>var tag=document.createElement("script");tag.src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";var firstScriptTag=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag,firstScriptTag);var player;function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){player=new YT.Player("player",{height:"390",width:"640",videoId:"M7lc1UVf-VE",playerVars:{autoplay:1,controls:0},events:{onReady:onPlayerReady,onStateChange:onPlayerStateChange}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo()}var done=!1;function onPlayerStateChange(a){a.data!=YT.PlayerState.PLAYING||done||(setTimeout(stopVideo,6E3),done=!0)}function playVideo(){player.playVideo()}function pauseVideo(){player.pauseVideo()}function stopVideo(){player.stopVideo()}function loadVideoById(a){player.loadVideoById(a,0,"large")};</script>`
   ```