# <script> in PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube, volume

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube Volume Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <?php echo 
        "<script>
          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '0',
              width: '0',
              playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
              videoId: 'CnIjyqhbLi0',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady}
            });
          }
          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.setVolume(50);
          }
        </script>";
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far and I would like to put it in php echo, but obviously the quotes inside the script tag interfere please help soon!

Comment: Why put this in a PHP `echo`? You could close a PHP block before with `?>` and open a new one after with `<?php`

Comment: you should get a look here :http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Why would you bring that into the PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use HEREDOC syntax as follows:

```
echo <<<CODE
     <!-- Place code here -->
CODE;
```

There can be nothing else (not even spaces on the CODE; line). Examples of Heredoc can be seen here: [What is the advantage of using Heredoc in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php)

If you don't want to use Heredoc, then you would need to escape every instance of your quotes with a backslash (\).