# pass variable from php to be used in jq

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to pass a php variable from php page and use that variable in jq.

trying to assing to the image a class that is a php variable

the php code:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
$pro_makat=$row["product_makat"];
$pro_id = $row['product_id'];
$products_list .= <<<EOT

<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h3 id="title" style="color:#cc00cc;">{$row["product_title"]}</h3>
<div><a href=""><img id="image" src="admin_area/product_images/{$row['product_image']}" class="$id" ></a></div>
```

and that image class $id I want to use in my jq code

```
    $(".$id").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post("product_details.php", {
        makat : $('#makat').val()
    }, 
        function(data){

        }
    );
```

how is it possible to make it work?

Comment: [tag:jq] is a Linux command line utility for handling JSON data. Is that really what you want here?

Comment: im new to programming but heres basically what im trying to do:
get images from the db with while(){} and each image to have same class but unique value for that class so I can manipulate it with jq (make a unique popup window for each image)

Comment: `".$id"` is invalid you should do `".$id."` notice the missing `.` this is like the `+` in javascript, for string concatenation .

Comment: @svidlak You can't do any of what you want with [tag:jq]. If you mean [tag:jQuery] then say jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

to echo an variable inside html/javascript just do:

```
$(".<?php echo $id ?>").click(function(e) {
....
```

...assuming you are OUT of the EOT

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it but for a syntax error.

```
 $('.".$id"').click(function(e) { 
 ....
```

Should be

```
 $('.".$id."').click(function(e) {
  ....
```

Notice the missing `.` which is like the `+` in javascipt or the concatenation operator.  But you still will need the css selector such as `.` for class and `#` for id, and be sure to not forget the `'` single quote for the javascript.  Although I am pretty sure because you have a `HEREDOC`, you could get away with just doing this instead `$(."{$id}")...`  or `$(.'{$id}')...` maybe even just `$(.'$id')...`

I know it gets a bit confusing with all these different languages using different symbols, or using them for different things.  Personally I'm not a big fan of PHP using the `.`, but because of the loose typing the `+` is out because you can actually add string values in php such as  `'1' + 1 = 2` so you see that is one of the reason PHP uses that instead of the plus.  What should PHP do in that case add them or make it `11`?  So they use the dot.

That is assuming this is all within the heredoc `<<<EOT` otherwise you'll need to use `<?php echo $id; ?>`

I love heredocs ... just saying.
[What is the advantage of using Heredoc in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php)

Just for clarity when using the HEREDOC or NEWDOC you have to end them on their own line.  So you have to do them like this

```
$a = array(
    'content' =>  <<<DOC


DOC
);
```

OR

```
$content =  <<<DOC


DOC;
```

Same for NEWDOC with is like the `'` single quote in that there is no variable interpolation so

```
$novar = 'Hello';

echo  <<<'DOC'
$novar
DOC;

echo  <<<DOC
$novar
DOC;
```

So the first prints

```
 $novar
```

But the second prints

```
 Hello
```

Comment: he will still need the `.` before the "id" to make jQuery search for the classname

Comment: There are also newdoc, so the heredoc is like the `"` and the new doc `<<<'DOC'` is like the `'` the trick with them is the ending must be on a line by themself and must end the line.  Including no indents.