# PHP is cutting my string

Tags: php, string

I'm having problems with a string, I don't know why but my string is being cutted off. I write this (where L::something are translated texts):

```
$secondHtml = "<div style='display:block; width:100%; height:30%; padding:0; padding-top:30px; margin:0; background:#ffffff'>
                <p style='font-weight:bold; text-align:center; '>".L::miregalo."</p><p style='text-align:center; '>".L::detalle.': ' . round($row["var"]/100,2) . '&euro; ' . $row["var"]."</p>
                <p style='text-align:center; padding-bottom:30px'>$mensajelink</p>
                <div style='display:block; font-size:12px; float:left; width:440px; min-height:200px; padding:10px; margin-right:20px;padding-left:0;'>
                    <p>$var2<a href='http://www.myweb.com/user/register' target='_blank' style='color:#009BAE;text-decoration:none;'>".L::registrate."</a></p>
                    <p>$var1<span style='color:#009BAE;'>". $row['var'] ."</span></p>
                </div>";
```

And I'm getting this:

```
<div style='display:block; width:100%; height:30%; padding:0; padding-top:30px; margin:0; background:#ffffff'>
                <p style='font-weight:bold; text-align:center; '>Nire oparia zertan datza?</p><p style='text-align:center; '>Opariaren xehetasuna: 0&euro; hurrengo tokian: <a href='http://www.myweb.com/eu/commerce/28/STORE'><span style='color:#009BAE;'>STORE</span></a></p>
                <p style='text-align:center; padding-bottom:30px'>Ikusi tokiak <a href='http://myweb.com' target='_blank' style='color:#009BAE; font-style:italic; text-decoration:none;'><span class='primera-font'>Web-n</span></a></p>
                <div style='display:block; font-size:12px; float:left; width:440px; min-height:200px; padding:10px; margin-right:20px;padding-left:0;'>
                    <p>Zure oparia beste toki baten aldatzea nahi baduzu edo erabilera epea aldatu, <a href='http://www.myweb.com/user/register' target='_blank' style='color:#009BAE;text-decoration:none;'>Izena eman</a></p>
                    <p>Aukeratutako tokian truk
```

The last words are part of a translated string, and I don't know why is cutting it. Additionaly, if I put the whole string in one line I get the next text:

```
(the initial part is the same)... target='_blank' style='color:#009BAE;text-decoration:none;'>Izena eman</a></p> <p>Aukeratutako tokian trukatzen baduzu, balioaren %2-
```

So my question is, I'm creating a too long string? Is there a maximum size? The maximum size is really so small?

Comment: Where does `L::something` come from? Is it a static method in some class?

Comment: Will you be able to add `$val` value?

Comment: I'm using a library, https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

Comment: add to the string do you mean AG21? I've got no error but no text is added to the $secondHtml variable.

Comment: @JonZangitu I mean to add in question.

Comment: Assuming you hardcode the `L::something` texts, does the output still get cut off?

Comment: I have hardcoded and is still getting cutted off Andrew...

Comment: Well at least that library is not the problem, leave them hardcoded for now. How are you outputting the string?

Comment: I'm using a library to output in PDF format, but debugging I'm watching the variable before outputing anything and is cutted off! I don't understand.

Comment: You're gonna have to post more code. Start by posting the library name and preferably a link to the github and the code to your class, or whatever it is that takes care of the output itself.

Comment: I'm reviewing it, but in the translate library I have some html code in the variables I'm using, and maybe the single-double quotes are the issue.

Comment: Maybe instead of using `"` and `'` try using the [heredoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php) see if that makes a difference. Either way, more code pl0x.