# Why JavaScript won't run properly on CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Good evening for You from Indonesia.
Nice to meet You all.

Okay, We have some problem about JavaScript on CodeIgniter.
This is the HTML (view), we want to run a simple JavaScript, just to know that JavaScript can run properly.
But I cannot see the "alert" dialog from JavaScript. What's wrong with this code?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Aluminium - Persebaran Alumni</title>

<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/datepicker3.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/styles.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Icons-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/lumino.glyphs.js');?>"></script>

<!-- javascript menampilkan lokasi saat ini -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function all() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
  var centreGot = false;
</script>

<!-- konfigurasi library googlemaps oleh biostall -->
<?php
  echo $map['js']
?>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body onload="all()">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Aluminium</span> Pencarian Alumni</a>
        <ul class="user-menu">
          <li class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> <?php echo $nama; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni/profile_alumni');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni/logout');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div id="sidebar-collapse" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav menu">
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked dashboard-dial"><use xlink:href="#stroked-dashboard-dial"></use></svg> Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('TracerStudy');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked table"><use xlink:href="#stroked-table"></use></svg> Tracer Study</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni/PersebaranAlumni');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked map"><use xlink:href="#stroked-map"></use></svg> Pencarian Alumni</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni/InfoGrafik');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked line-graph"><use xlink:href="#stroked-line-graph"></use></svg> Informasi Grafik</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Alumni/Stakeholder');?>"><svg class="glyph stroked pencil"><use xlink:href="#stroked-pencil"></use></svg> Stakeholder</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="attribution">Template by <a href="http://www.medialoot.com/item/lumino-admin-bootstrap-template/">Medialoot</a><br/><a href="http://www.glyphs.co" style="color: #333;">Icons by Glyphs</a></div>
  </div><!--/.sidebar-->

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Peta Aluminium</h1>
      </div>
    </div><!--/.row-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" id="lat_lng">
        <FORM NAME="rd" METHOD="POST" ACTION="index.html">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="long" ID="long" VALUE="">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lat" ID="lat" VALUE="">
        </FORM>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="haversin"><?php echo anchor('Alumni/prosesHaversine', 'Haversine');?></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php
          echo $map['html'];
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  <!--/.main-->


  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/chart.min.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/chart-data.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/easypiechart.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/easypiechart-data.js');?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js');?>"></script>
  <script>
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
    });

    !function ($) {
      $(document).on("click","ul.nav li.parent > a > span.icon", function(){
        $(this).find('em:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
      });
      $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    }(window.jQuery);

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      if ($(window).width() > 768) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('show')
    })
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      if ($(window).width() <= 767) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('hide')
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

End this is the JavaScript that we want running properly.

```
<!-- javascript menampilkan lokasi saat ini -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function all() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
  var centreGot = false;
</script>
```

I'm sorry if this is just newbie's question. I'm very happy, and thanks a lot for your good advice or suggestion.

Comment: you should check inspector to check all javascript files are loaded. If a script error occurs, following script will not work.

Comment: Just ran the code snippet and it worked my side

Comment: I've found the mistake. If we are running the javascript on the pure html (It has not a session), the javascript can run properly. But after I try it on the session, It will not run properly.

Comment: Thank you @blacmoon, do you have any experience about that ?

Comment: Thank you @Tiwaz89 , Yes of course The Javascript can run properly if it has outside the session. But, if the javascript is inside the session, it will won't run properly. Have you any a good solution about that?

Comment: Post your controller code here? something is added before the $this->load->view();

Comment: Can't find. Is it fixed?

Comment: @blacmoon Thank you for your attention and time. sorry if I was late to inform you the controller's file. This is it, https://pastebin.com/Jw416iUh

Comment: Not yet @blacmoon , I hope you can give me some good solution.

Comment: I saw your pastebin, looks fine. may be problem with saving the script, can you try to save the script using heredoc ($config['onboundschanged'] ). Ref:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php

Comment: Thanks @blacmoon for your help, I had found solution, and now It has run properly. In my solution, I have put the javascript on the controller (with echo). And JavaScript can do perfectly, like what I want to do. I've appreciate for your time, atention, and help. Nice to meet you, and see you again on the stackoverflow :)

Comment: Happy coding :D