# Call function from php page

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm trying to display html from a php page on my home page. 
I have a function to call some html in a php page called home-content.php

```
<?php function HomeFeed ($replStr) {
return <<<HTML
  <div class="wider-width">
   <div class="col-full">

    <table class="homefeed1">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><center><h1>Store Location</h1>
        <h4>Address Line 1<br>
        Address Line 2<br></h4></br><h2><strong>Hours</strong></h2><br>
        <h4>10 AM to 6:30 PM Monday through Friday</h4><br>
        <h4>9 AM to 2 PM Saturday</h4><br
        <h2>Call Now</h2><h4>(903) 769-8043</h4></center>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
HTML;
}
?>
```

Now I have my homepage template that I want to call that function to display the html. Now, I'm sure this is all entirely wrong but I'm new to trying to use php, so I've moved thing around a lot and everything. I had it almost working at one point, the html was displaying but it also showed the HomeFeed return <<

```
<?php
require_once('home-content.php');
?>

HomeFeed()
```

Comment: didn't you wrap this `HomeFeed()` in php tags?

Comment: why is this edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16812697 attemping to fix code? it should be rejected. This is not allowed. Edit: and *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."* was the reason to be rejected.

Comment: I actually thought it was a mistake you made

Comment: You called a php function outside php tags

Comment: @HenryBbosa *"I actually thought it was a mistake you made"* - Mistakes that can be edited are typos from text, not code. You can tag edit also, just not "code", please remember that.

Comment: hahahaha got it @Fred-ii-

Comment: @HenryBbosa thanks Henry, *cheers*

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the function call within the php escape tags. Also you might want to consider revising the function as follows.

```
<?php
    require_once('home-content.php');
    HomeFeed();
?>

<?php function HomeFeed () { ?>

  <div class="wider-width">
   <div class="col-full">

    <table class="homefeed1">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><center><h1>Store Location</h1>
        <h4>Address Line 1<br>
        Address Line 2<br></h4></br><h2><strong>Hours</strong></h2><br>
        <h4>10 AM to 6:30 PM Monday through Friday</h4><br>
        <h4>9 AM to 2 PM Saturday</h4><br
        <h2>Call Now</h2><h4>(903) 769-8043</h4></center>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No `echo` needed if HTML is returned - which it is.

Comment: okay.  I'll edit.

Comment: I've tried it that way and it didn't work either.

Comment: Also I would recommend changing the function to echo the results or escape to html if that makes sense.

Comment: It throws an error with php tags: https://computerconceptsofhl.com/

Comment: @Brian could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Brian that is just not necessary. [Heredocs are perfectly valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php).

Comment: BOOM this answer actually did work after i copied it exactly. I only noticed you wrapping the function call in php tags which i had already done before.

Comment: Cool.  Also if you want more functionality you could use the php brackets to include echo variables, loops, and if statements

Answer (score 0):

try this Assign string to variable and echo it:

Wrap your function call inside php tags..

```
   <?php function HomeFeed () {

$returnstring = <<<HTML
  <div class="wider-width">
   <div class="col-full">

    <table class="homefeed1">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><center><h1>Store Location</h1>
        <h4>Address Line 1<br>
        Address Line 2<br></h4></br><h2><strong>Hours</strong></h2><br>
        <h4>10 AM to 6:30 PM Monday through Friday</h4><br>
        <h4>9 AM to 2 PM Saturday</h4><br
        <h2>Call Now</h2><h4>(903) 769-8043</h4></center>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
HTML;
echo $returnstring;
}
?>
    <?php
     require_once('home-content.php');
      HomeFeed();
    ?>
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to echo HTML if HTML is returned.

Comment: I am not returning its an assignment

Comment: You are echoing the assignment.

Comment: yes the variable contents

Comment: It's not necessary.

Comment: okay.. then correct me please

Comment: I did already, in the first comment I made to you. A quick test by you will reveal the echo is unnecessary.

Comment: okay..Thanks alot