# Concatenate HTML string and variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

This solution to concatenate HTML string and variable is not convenient because we need to interrupt the string:

```
$content = '<meta property="foo" url="' . $url . '" name="' . $name . '">';
```

whereas this one is not handy because we have to escape `"` by `\"`:

```
$content = "<meta property=\"foo\" url=\"$url\" name=\"$name\">";
```

**What other solution (not requiring an extra function) would you use that would improve code readability?**

---

Note: not a duplicate of heredoc related questions because here I'm looking for a one-line solution.

Comment: You know you can use a single quote `'` for the HTML attributes...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to make working code better belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @TomUdding So what would be your solution?

Comment: @Quentin No this queston is really code related, and codereview is intended for longer code review than just this.

Comment: (not requiring an extra function) pity sprintf is perfect for this

Comment: Then it is off-topic because code readability is largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: `$content = "<meta property='foo' url='$url' name='$name'>";` and voila, a perfectly readable string.

Comment: Just put markup with markup and use a templating engine like e.g. twig

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using Heredoc in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php)

Comment: @revo No, heredoc needs many lines, whereas i'm looking for a one-liner.

Comment: If you are describing beginning / ending delimiters as *many lines*, you may be right.

Comment: @TomUdding I often see `"` used in HTML attributes, maybe more often than `'` is there a reason (historical, code readibility, etc.)?

Comment: @Basj It doesn't really matter, it works the same. It is probably someone's decision to choose for one of the two options. I prefer to use `"` for my `echo` and within what I echo `'`.

Comment: @TomUdding so you do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595318/1422096)?

Comment: @Basj Yes and I use the curly braces because I can use [complex expressions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Comment: @TomUdding Thanks. I don't understand why so many downvotes :) About the probable duplicates: Heredoc is clearly another topic, [such questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string) are clearly another topic because it doesn't deal with single quote / double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes for raw HTML and curly braces around PHP variables. Like so;

```
$content = "<meta property='foo' url='{$url}' name='{$name}'>";
```

Comment: Thanks! It even seems to work without the curly braces: `$content = "<meta property='foo' url='$url' name='$name'>";`

Comment: One drawback @Mark: if `$name = "I don't know";` it won't work, because the single quote of `don't` will break the code.

Comment: This is true - you could get around that by using `htmlentities()`. You should process your variables using this method before passing them into HTML. Something similar to `$url = htmlentities($url, ENT_NOQUOTES)`. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) for more details

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use:

```
$url = ...;
$name = ...;
$content = sprintf('<meta property="foo" url="%s" name="%s">', $url, $name);
```

which is a very fast way to produce `HTML markup` keeping a good readability. If you don't want to use additional functions, your only solution is to use double quotes `"` externally and single quotes `'` for `HTML attributes`.

Comment: Why the downvotes, +1 from me

Comment: @lloiacono — The OP explicitly ruled out additional functions in the question and sprintf, in particular, in a comment.

Comment: There's a serial downvoter who downvoted everything @lloiacono ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try heredoc notation:

```
    $content = <<<DOC
<meta property="foo" url="$url" name="$name">
DOC;
```