# how to change onclick function with double quote in variable

Tags: javascript, php

```
$status="<div  class='analysis btn btn-secondary' ><a id='$poupid' href='javascript: void 0;' onclick='open_windowdata(this.href,this.id)' style='color:white'><strong>Not attempted</strong></a></div>";
```

just need to replace onclick with below code

```
onclick="$('#wiewans_<?php echo $slno; ?>').slideToggle('slow')"
```

facing with trouble quote 
any one help us thanks

Comment: What is your expected `$status`?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ankit  onclick='open_windowdata(this.href,this.id)'  need to replace onclick="$('#wiewans_<?php echo $slno; ?>').slideToggle('slow')"

Comment: @Gajendra use backquote to surround the entire text.

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes like so `onclick=\"open_...slow')\" ...`

Comment: _or_ make use of php's [HEREDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php) syntax

Comment: _but_ I'd recommend to do a call to a simple js function outside, that includes the jQuery script. That would make it much more readable and maintainable

Comment: In any case unless you'll be using eval in php, you should be doing those changes on your source code, not in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the double quotes with ' \ ', this way they wont get parsed as end of the string :

```
$status = "<div class='analysis btn btn-secondary'><a id='$poupid' href='javascript: void 0;' onclick=\"$('#wiewans_<?php echo $slno; ?>').slideToggle('slow');\" style='color:white'><strong>Not attempted</strong></a></div>";
```