# How do get HTML content for a function between PHP tags?

Tags: php

It's a simple question but I've never seen a way to solve it. I would like to pass my HTML to a function between PHP Tags

Example:

```
<?php $thisVar = ?>
    <h2>Here is my desired HTML<h2>
    <p>Here is my desired HTML<p>
<?php ; callFunction($thisVar);?>
```

I know it's not possible this way, so i do something like this:

```
<?php $thisVar = '
  <h2>Here is my desired HTML<h2>
  <p>Here is my desired HTML<p>
'; callFunction($thisVar);?>
```

or even

```
<?php callFunction('
  <h2>Here is my desired HTML<h2>
  <p>Here is my desired HTML<p>
');?>
```

The last 2 examples work, but when i'm working with long HTMLs as variables it gets unorganized. Is there a way to do like the first example? Opening and Closing the PHP tag before and after the desired HTML variable?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to have a read about HEREDOC - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-heredoc-in-php

Comment: If there is a very long `html`, then you can save it in a file like file.txt and then call `<?php $thisVar = file_get_contents('path/to/file.txt'); ?> `