# PHP three less than signs

Tags: php, heredoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, what does “<<<” represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700042/in-php-what-does-represent)

I was just looking around in some example docs, and I seen this:

```
$page = <<<CHART
<html><head> head code
</head><body>
body code
</body>
</html>
CHART;
return $page;
```

I just want to know what the first line means and why someone would use this? Also, if I could read more on this too? I assume to end the CHART would be the "CHART;" since it's at the end and the same as the beginning.

Thanks