# what means <<< in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, what does “<<<” represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700042/in-php-what-does-represent)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

can anyone explain me what means those chars? belowe variable contains string:

```
$txt = <<<EOD
this is simple string
EOD;

$x = ...
```

can I change `<<<` for `'` ?

Comment: google -> `what means <<<EOD in php`. is it so hard?

Comment: thank you @Quentin I didint know that this post exists

Comment: I have to agree that it's a bit difficult to search for `<<<` here on SO and on Google actually. However if you start typing `<<<` on the PHP manual search page (http://us3.php.net/manual-lookup.php) you get `string` as first suggestion in the typeahead list. This is not a critic, I just want you to make aware of the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called here-document.

For general info:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

For php specific info:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

And it is NOT the same as '...'

Answer (score 3):

It's what is called a heredoc.

> Heredoc
>
> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this
>   operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself
>   follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.
>   Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other
>   label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc