# What does <<<OUT mean in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, what does “<<<” represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700042/in-php-what-does-represent)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I ran into this in a PHP script.

(Be aware, I'm new at this so I might look dumb)

```
$Var['Text'] = <<<OUT
String Here
OUT;
```

Comment: What is the point of that now?! There is nothing in the string, anyways thanks.

Comment: Please see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called the Heredoc syntax to mark strings. **[Check it out!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**

Answer (score 0):

It's a heredoc. Think multi line string.

Answer (score 0):

It is called heredoc, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).
It is another way to create strings.