# How to write php code snippet inside html without running php scripts

Tags: javascript, php, html, backend

I just started learning php, And I'm stuck on how to write php code snippet inside html.
When I try `<pre>`, and `<code>` the php code starts running itself. I have named the file as run.php and I want to show this code as a snippet like the below one

```html
<?php
echo "<h2>PHP is Fun!</h2>";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
echo "I'm about to learn PHP!<br>";
echo "This ", "string ", "was ", "made ", "with multiple parameters.";
?>
```

And I want to show as it is, I don't want run the code. Please help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just have it outside the `?>`  and `<?`  like this `<?php $something="something"; ?>echo raw php here and escape the < with &lt; <? here we are in php again`

Comment: Can you use `&lt;` and `&gt;` in place of your php angle brackets? Or make sure the file is a .html file, not .php.

Answer (score 0):

This has been closed as a duplicate of [display-html-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html) and while, in principle the same applies here, there are some notable caveats.

The PHP interpreter is looking for the magic string "<?php" - that's what you need to encode in the source file to prevent PHP execution. And also any occurrence of "?>" within your snippets. You can apply the substitutions documented, or simply break the string:

```
print "<?" . "php";
```

However you still need to encode other stuff to prevent it being interpreted as a directive to the browser.

PHP provides a function for doing this: [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

This will automatically replace any of the control structures used in HTML.

But PHP goes further - specifically for rendering PHP source code, you can use the [highlight_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file) and [highlight_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) functions. These will do the character replacements but also apply colours to the output to make it easier to visualize.

(there's also third party libraries, e.g. [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), which can do this for PHP and other programming languages).

I would recommend you consider using highlight_file() to keep the PHP content you want to show separate from the code you want to execute - it can get quite confusing when you are only embedding PHP in HTML or vice-versa - as you add layers ots going to get confusing as to what is code and what is content.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `highlight_string()`:

```
<?php
   $mycode = <<<CODE
   <?php
   echo "<h2>PHP is Fun!</h2>";
   echo "Hello world!<br>";
   echo "I'm about to learn PHP!<br>";
   echo "This ", "string ", "was ", "made ", "with multiple parameters.";
   ?> 
   CODE;

   highlight_string($mycode);
?>
```

Live example: http://135.125.201.97/so0001.php (exactly the code above)

It's a nice function, as it colorizes the PHP syntax. Please note that `highlight_string()` echoes the code by default. If you want to use `echo` you need to set the second parameter to true:

```
echo highlight_string($mycode,true);
```

Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php).

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700042/in-php-what-does-represent) (about how to use `<<<` and what does it do).